# Fallout 4 DLC Items in Base Game

Tags: fallout-4

With Far Harbor and Nuka World installed, are any items added to the game's loot table from the beginning, or are they only available after traveling to the DLC locations?

Comment: IIRC, the Fallout 4 DLCs don't have scripts to inject items into leveled lists, so they cannot appear in the base game, but that's going from a few months ago. However, in my hundreds of hours with DLC installed I played I never saw a DLC weapon in the base game area, or the ammo for it.

Comment: There's definitely no 7.62 ammo to be found without travelling to Nuka World.

Answer (score 3):

Like @SGR said for the majority of the loot that you find in the base game area will not be from the DLC. However, I have seen legendary drops which are from one DLC that will either show up in a different DLC and I believe also in the base game area. For instance, I once found a lever-action rifle in the Nuka DLC before starting Far Harbor.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It happened to me to find consumables from Far Harbor in the base map, such as Vims.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have Far-Harbor and Nukaworld installed, I don't think you'll find any loot from the DLCs in the base Area. However, It happened to me to find DLC loot dropped by ennemies found in both DLC and Base areas, while killing them in the Base area, for exemple Raiders, found both in Nuka work and the base Area, but it might just be NukaWorld that added those ennemies.

Answer (score 0):

Started a new game recently and I dropped a Far Harbor weapon in the base game (around level 20). This seems to be very rare though and I haven't found any ammo for it yet.

The only DLC quest I have for now is the Automatron one, so Far Harbor is not accessible yet. All DLC are enabled.